# Question Regarding $\int_0^1\int_0^∞ e^{-xy}-xye^{-xy}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Specifically for $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xy}-xye^{-xy}dx$,
I see that this inner integral evaluates to $xe^{-xy}$ from x = zero to x = infinity, which after plugging in, comes out to be zero (according to my textbook). However, I stuck on how to evaluate $xe^{-xy}$  for x = infinity. I tried to solve it by rephrasing it to $$\lim \limits_{x \to {\infty}}\frac{x}{e^{xy}}$$
But I realized there is no l'hopital's rule for multiple variables.

Any hints or answers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-xy)^{-xy}dx~dy$$
Let $xy=t$,then
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{y}\int_{0}^{\infty} (1-t)e^{-t} dt=0$$

Answer (score 0):

When you are integrating w.r.t $x$ you are treating $y$ as a  constant. So L'Hopital's Rule is applicable and $\lim \frac x {e^{xy}}=\lim \frac  1{ ye^{xy}} =0$ for any $y>0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $xe^{-xy}=x(e^y)^{-x}$.  For any $y \in (0,1), e^y$ is a constant $k$ greater than $1$, and we know $\frac x{k^x} \to 0$.  As changing the value of the integrand at one point does not change the integral, we can ignore what happens at $y=0$.